# How to link each menu of any dropdown list of the topnav bar in every page with its matching tab panel in another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a top navbar in every page of a multipage website.
Each menu of the top navbar has a dropdown list.

Each of my inner pages has a sidenav bar (tabs) on the left (one level hierarchy) and a body on the right- which is the tab panels.

I want to link each menu of any dropdown list of the topnav with its matching tab panel in any inner page WITH MAKING THE MATCHING SIDENAV MENU SELECTED as well

example: https://www.amherst.edu
when you click on "Our Open Curriculum" from "The Academic Experience"
it opens directly the tab panel "Our Open Curriculum" (on the right)
AND the "Our Open Curriculum" on the left IS SELECTED, as well.

HOW can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current page url store it in one variable(url). After that by using jquery selector ( $("[href='"+url+"']") )  apply the active style or class.